# XMLUnit: How to register a self-closing element as different to a non-self-closing element?

Tags: java, html, xml, xmlunit-2

I want to compare two empty elements with the same qualified name. I want to be able to specify an option which marks the elements as different if one is self-closing and the other is not.

```java
final String control = "<a></a>";
final String test = "<a/>";
Diff myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(control))
    .withTest(Input.fromString(test))
    .build();
System.out.println(myDiff.toString());
```

This currently prints

```java
[identical]
```

How can I instead make it contain a difference?

I have explored the `ComparisonType` enum, but it does not seem to contain any values which match the type of comparison I seek.

I am using Java 8 and XMLUnit for Java 2.5.0.

Context: The reason I want to do this is because I have an XSLT transformation converting XML to HTML, and I am writing a unit test ensuring that the output does not contain self-closing `<div/>`s or `<p/>`s, as this is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, for a very simple reason: the two elements aren't different. Only their serialized forms are different, and XMLUnit is concerned with whether the XML is correct, not whether it is serialized the way you want it serialized.

Comment: I appreciate that, by the XML model, the two elements are identical. Still, given that I want a test for this to check that I am generating correct HTML, I had hoped I would not have to delve into the murky waters of comparing String serializations of XML directly.

Comment: unfortunately you will have to. XMLUnit runs your serialized form through an XML parser and won't even know one of the elements has been self-closing.

Comment: Note that in the W3C QT3 and XSLT3 test suites we explicitly allowed for this: as well as test assertions against the XML model, these also allow assertions against the serialized output - but the design is very careful to keep these two things separate. And you're right, tests against the serialized output can get very murky: the trick is to only test one small aspect of the result, e.g. `serialization-matches("/>")`.